# SQL request to select from table two recent records with specific field for each item

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL request to select from table two recent records with specific value field.

Hi people.
My knowledge of SQL is not enough, so I ask you help.
I have table with units and table with unit services unit_service

```
id     unit_id    date         mileage    type
1        2       2000-12-01     1000       6
2        3       2000-07-07     1000       7
3        2       2000-07-01     1000       6
4        3       2000-08-03     1000       6
5        3       2000-08-03     1000       7
6        3       2000-08-04     1000       8
7        2       2000-08-04     1000       6
```

and so on... type is type of service.

I want to get list of units with two latest dates for each type of service and print it then in table.
For now, I am build this request

```
SELECT
   u.unit_number, us.mileage, us.type, us.date
FROM
   units AS u
LEFT JOIN
   units_service AS us ON (u.id = us.unit_id)
WHERE
   (us.id = ( SELECT us2.id
              FROM units_service AS us2
              WHERE us2.unit_id=us.unit_id AND us2.type = 6
              ORDER BY us2.date DESC LIMIT 1)
    OR us.id = ( SELECT us2.id
                 FROM units_service AS us2
                 WHERE us2.unit_id=us.unit_id AND us2.type = 6
                 ORDER BY us2.date DESC LIMIT 1,1)
    OR us.id = ( SELECT us2.id
                 FROM units_service AS us2
                 WHERE us2.unit_id=us.unit_id AND us2.type = 7
                 ORDER BY us2.date DESC LIMIT 1)
    OR us.id = ( SELECT us2.id
                 FROM units_service AS us2
                 WHERE us2.unit_id=us.unit_id AND us2.type = 7
                 ORDER BY us2.date DESC LIMIT 1,1)
    OR us.id = ( SELECT us2.id
                 FROM units_service AS us2
                 WHERE us2.unit_id=us.unit_id AND us2.type = 8
                 ORDER BY us2.date DESC LIMIT 1))
    OR us.id = ( SELECT us2.id
                 FROM units_service AS us2
                 WHERE us2.unit_id=us.unit_id AND us2.type = 8
                 ORDER BY us2.date DESC LIMIT 1,1)
    AND u.unit_company = :unit_company
    AND u.unit_type = :unit_type
ORDER BY us.unit_id
```

Is this request bad or good? Is another request or few requests what better for this?
Or maybe you think, what better is to use some another tables?

Regards.

Comment: `LIMIT 2, 1` gets the first and third dates.  I think you mean `LIMIT 1, 1`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, yes, you right my mistake. I'll fix it.

Comment: Can you provide the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  This solves the problem in one condition:

```
WHERE us.id = ANY (SELECT us2.id
                   FROM units_service us2
                   WHERE us2.unit_id = us.unit_id AND us2.type = us.type
                   ORDER BY us2.date DESC
                   LIMIT 2
                  )
```

(I haven't tried `ANY` with a subquery that has `LIMIT` in MySQL; I know `IN` does not work in Mysql -- although it works in other databases.)

If the above doesn't work the following should:

```
WHERE us.id = (SELECT us2.id
               FROM units_service us2
               WHERE us2.unit_id=  us.unit_id AND us2.type = us.type
               ORDER BY us2.date DESC
               LIMIT 1
              ) OR
      us.id = (SELECT us2.id
               FROM units_service us2
               WHERE us2.unit_id = us.unit_id AND us2.type = us.type
               ORDER BY us2.date DESC
               LIMIT 1, 1
              )
```

Comment: It's a left join and 'us' is on the right side. The above should be a part of the join, not the where clause.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried (ANY) and have  _This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'_ (MySQL Server version: 5.7.17)

Comment: I have made little modification in second code and it work properly now.

Comment: I have modified it's so WHERE (us.id = (SELECT us2.id
               FROM units_service us2
               WHERE us2.unit_id=  us.unit_id AND us2.type = us.type
               ORDER BY us2.date DESC
               LIMIT 1
              ) OR
      us.id = (SELECT us2.id
               FROM units_service us2
               WHERE us2.unit_id = us.unit_id AND us2.type = us.type
               ORDER BY us2.date DESC
               LIMIT 1, 1
              ))
              AND u.unit_company = :unit_company
       AND u.unit_type = :unit_type